# how to configure mysql to restrict camel case

Tags: mysql

I have a database of MySQL in local host . It is converted to lower-case automatically for any import .

But my live server database is in camel case format.

How to make my local database restricted to camel case ?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the lower_case_table_names variable from /mysql/bin/my.ini file.

Change it's value from 2 to 0.

For details explanation go through : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html